# Cannot convert IQueryable to Generlic List EF 4

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I can't figure out why I get this error trying to get back a list of my type TemplateArea.

```
List<TemplateArea> templateAreas = _context.TemplateAreas.Where(ec => ec.TemplateId == templateTypeId);

> I get "Cannot convert source type
> System.Linq.IQueryable<Nike.Data.Domain.Model.TemplateArea> to target
> System.Collections.Generic.List<Nike.Data.Domain.Model.TemplateArea>"
```

I'm using Entity Framework v4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the .ToList() extension method.

```
List<TemplateArea> templateAreas = _context.TemplateAreas.Where(ec => ec.TemplateId == templateTypeId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ToList` extension method.

```
List<TemplateArea> templateAreas = _context.TemplateAreas
                .Where(ec => ec.TemplateId == templateTypeId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

this should to the trick:

```
List<TemplateArea> templateAreas = _context.TemplateAreas.Where(ec => ec.TemplateId == templateTypeId).ToList();
```